# php calculation multiplication for a date

Tags: php, date, calculation

Can someone please help me, I am trying to make this work. 
If the date is a Sunday then I want it to times hourly rate by 1.5.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$date ='2017/09/24';
$Hours ='';// removed to keep private
$Hourly_rate='';// removed to keep private
$sundaypay = $Hourly_rate*1.5;
 if(date('w', strtotime($date)) == 7):
  $pay = ($Hours * $sundaypay);
 else:
  $pay = ($Hours * $Hourly_rate);
 endif;
?>
```

it is not working and just outputs the else even though 2017/09/24 was a Sunday. Does anyone know why

```
if(date('w', strtotime($date)) == 7):
```

does not work?

```
<?php echo $pay;?>
```

Comment: is date('w', strtotime($date) printing 7? How do you debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up a php manual for [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

There you will see that `w` format option is described as

> Numeric representation of the day of the week: 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)

See? There's no `7`, just numbers from `0` to `6`.

Either compare to `0`, or use `N` format option, which is:

> ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in PHP 5.1.0): 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)

```
if(date('N', strtotime($date)) == 7)
// or
if(date('w', strtotime($date)) == 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, this has worked! I have used N in the past. I didn't know the number would have changed, I thought I wrote it out wrong just shows you have to check everything!